# If $t_n\uparrow t$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\tau\le t_n\right\}=\left\{\tau\le t\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ be bounded above and nonempty
- $\tau:\Omega\to I\cup\sup I$
- $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be nondecreasing with $$t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t:=\sup I\tag1$$

> I want to show that $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\tau\le t_n\right\}=\left\{\tau\le t\right\}\;.\tag2$$

Since $$\left\{\tau\le t_n\right\}\subseteq\left\{\tau\le t\right\}\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\;,\tag3$$ we've clearly got "$\subseteq$". For the other inclusion, let $$\omega\in\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\tau\le t_n\right\}\right)^c=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\tau>t_n\right\}\;.\tag4$$ By definition, $$\tau(\omega)>t_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\,\tag5$$ but this only yields $$\tau(\omega)\ge\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}t_n=t\;,\tag6$$ i.e. $$\omega\in\left\{\tau\ge t\right\}=\left\{\tau<t\right\}^c\;.\tag7$$

> So, which argument do we need to conclude $\omega\in\left\{\tau\le t\right\}^c$?

Comment: (2) is not correct; it should read $$\bigcup_n \{\tau \leq t_n\} = \{\tau \color{red}{<} t\}.$$

Comment: @saz "$\subseteq$" of your relation is exactly $(7)$, but the other inclusion is not correct. Just take $t_n=t$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. BTW, the question arose in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2321116/47771) answer to my other question.

Comment: @saz Oh, and I guess you've intended to write $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{\tau<t_n\right\}=\left\{\tau<t\right\}$$ which is indeed correct.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @saz Do you agree that this relation is even correct when $\tau$ takes values in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ and $I$ is any subset of $\mathbb R$? I don't see any problem.

Comment: Yeah, should be okay... the only thing which is needed to prove the identity is the very definition of the supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something $\bigcup_n \{\tau \leq 1 - 1/n\}$ is a counter example. Note that none of the sets contain $1$ so it's union can't be $\{ \tau \leq 1\}$.